# Discontinuous set

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

We have a space $\mathcal{C}([0,1] \to \mathbb{R})$ of continuous functions on [0,1] and the uniform topology with the $sup$ metric. Define $\psi(f) = min\{1, \inf\{t \geq \frac{1}{2}: f(t) =0\}\}$. Find the set for which $\psi$ is discontinuous.

Attempt:

The isolated points at which $f(t)=0$ will be the points of discontinuity. So, the set will be all the points at which f(t)=0. If f(t) isn't 0, then $\psi = 1$ and is constant up until $f(t)$ becomes 0. At that instance, $\psi = t$. But my problem is that $f$ could be any continuous function. How do I choose a form for $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\psi$ is continuous at $f$ if, and only if, one of the following is true :

1. for every $\eta >0$, there are $t_1,t_2 \in I_\eta = [\psi(f) - \eta, \psi(f) + \eta] \cap[1/2,1]$ such that $f(t_1) >0$ and $f(t_2)<0$
2. $\psi(f) = 1$

**Proof**

Let $f\in \mathcal C([0,1],\mathbb R)$.

- If (1) is true, then, take $\varepsilon >0$ such that $f(t_1) > \varepsilon$, $f(t_2) < -\varepsilon$ and such that $|f|>\varepsilon$ on $[1/2,\psi(f) - \eta]$. (This is possible since $f$ is continuous and non-zero on this interval.) Then, if $\| f-g\| < \varepsilon$, $g$ cannot have a zero in $[1/2,\psi(f)- \eta]$ and does have a zero in $I_\eta$. Therefore, $|\psi(g) - \psi(f)|< \eta$.
- If (2) is true, for $\eta > 0$, take $\varepsilon = \inf_{[1/2,1- \eta]} |f|$. Then if $\| f-g\|_\infty < \varepsilon$, we have $|g| > 0$ on $[1/2,1-\eta]$ and therefore $|\psi(f) - \psi(g)| < \eta$.
- If (1) and (2) are false, then there exists $\eta >0$ such that $f$ has constant sign on $I_\eta$. Without loss of generality, we can assume $f\geqslant 0$ on $I_\eta$ and $1\notin I_\eta$. Then for every $\varepsilon >0$, we have $f + \varepsilon >0$ on $I_\eta$ and therefore $|\psi(f + \varepsilon) - \psi(f)|>\eta$.